# How to solve this question without calculus?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I was working on a task given by my Math teacher. The question has to be solved using the following diagram:

[image: Diagram related to the question]

The Question is as follows:

- Find the length ${AD}$ in terms of $\beta, \cos\beta,$ and/or $\tan\beta$.
- Find the length ${BC}$ in terms of $\beta, \cos\beta,$ and/or $\tan\beta$.

Another condition is: you cannot use calculus to solve this question (I don't know whether it is required or not though).

My attempt at the question:
While I was trying to solve the question, I was trying to figure out a relation by creating triangles and trying to come up with trigonometric equations using the angles given and the angles which can be figured out (that is, I was trying to see if I can use sin rule, cosine rule, etc.). But all of this was to no avail.

Comment: Draw a vertical line from  G to HC dividing triangle GHC, the length of this line is $h\over 2$. You can then calculate GH and HC. Use GH to calculate OH and BH then you have BC.

Comment: Draw from C a line parallel to EF and intersects with DE at J. Use triangle CDJ to calculate DJ; and with BC and DJ, you can calculate AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a vertical line from $G$ to the $x$ axis.  Call the intersecting point $M$.  Find the distance between $O$ and $M$.  Length $OM = r \cos\beta$.  Now you have the distance from $G$ to the $y$ axis.  Draw a vertical line upward from $G$ to create a right triangle with $DG$ as the hypotenuse.  Call the intersecting point $N$ between $D$ and $E$.  Realize the angle of $GDE$ is $\frac{\pi}{2} - \beta$.  The length $DN$ is $\frac{h}{2 \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta)}$.  Subtract the length of $DN$ from the length of $OM$ to get the length of $AD$.  Length $AD$ = $r \cos\beta - \frac{h}{2 \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta)}$.

The length of $BC$ is easily found from here. Draw a vertical line upward from $C$ to intersect with $DE$.  The intersection can be called $Z$.  The length $DZ$ is twice the length $DN$.  Add length $DZ$ to length $AD$ to yield length $BC$.  Length $BC = r \cos\beta - \frac{h}{2 \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta)} + \frac{h}{ \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta)} = r \cos\beta + \frac{h}{2 \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta)}$

Edit: Miscellaneous pointed out that $\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta)}$ is $\tan\beta$.  So, the answer simplifies to:

- Length $AD = r \cos\beta - \frac{h\tan\beta}{2}$
- Length $BC = r \cos\beta + \frac{h\tan\beta}{2}$

Comment: $\frac 1 {\tan(\frac π 2−β)}= \tanβ$

Comment: Some formatting hints: (1) mathjax all your mathematical notation, particularly those references to variable names. It makes them stand out from the surrounding text and thus easier to spot and read. (2) many commonly used mathematical operators - in particular, trigonometric function names, can be formatted simply by adding a "\" before the names (and a space or other punctuation after: \cosx would not be properly formatted because mathjax doesn't know a "cosx" function). I think you'll agree that `r\cos x` = $r\cos x$ is much better than `r cos x` = $r cos x$.

Comment: If you need to use an operator that mathjax doesn't recognize, you can either use `\text{coker}A` = $\text{coker}A$ or `\operatorname{coker}A` = $\operatorname{coker}A$. The advantage of operatorname is that it handles spacing for operators appropriately, while text is used for other purposes, so LaTex doesn't even know you are using it as an operator.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Helpful to know. I just started posting, so hints are great.